# Click button to toggle class of parent element - pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple divs on the page with the class 'item' – I'd like to include a button within the div that when clicked will toggle append/remove the class 'zoom' on the 'item' div…

```
<div class="item">
<button class="zoomer"></button>
</div>
```

I've found plenty of code examples that target an id element, but struggling to find a solution that works with multiples of the same class element on one page.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have buttons in all the divs with the class name item? If you do, you can add an event listener with  queryselectorall then create a function to toggle classes on click.

Comment: I'll update my answer for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all of the `buttons` and then you can use `forEach` so you can target the element's `item` parent.

```js
// Get all the buttons
let zoomer_button = document.querySelectorAll('.zoomer');

// Loop through the buttons.
// Arrow function allows to pass the element
zoomer_button.forEach(button => {
  // Add an event listener for a click on the button.
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // the e is the event, and then you check what the target is, which is the button.
    // then you can toggle a 'zoom' class on the parent 'item'
    e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('zoom');
  });
});
```

```css
.item.zoom {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <button class="zoomer">button</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button class="zoomer">button</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button class="zoomer">button</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button class="zoomer">button</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button class="zoomer">button</button>
</div>
```

If it's nested a layer deeper, you can use `parentNode` twice.

```js
// Get all the buttons
let zoomer_button = document.querySelectorAll('.zoomer');

// Loop through the buttons.
// Arrow function allows to pass the element
zoomer_button.forEach(button => {
  // Add an event listener for a click on the button.
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // the e is the event, and then you check what the target is, which is the button.
    // then you can toggle a 'zoom' class on the parent 'item'
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.toggle('zoom');
  });
});
```

```css
.item.zoom {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="media">
    <button class="zoomer">button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="media">
    <button class="zoomer">button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="media">
    <button class="zoomer">button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="media">
    <button class="zoomer">button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated with question. We could get into `functions` to do the nesting check, but this will work for basic needs.

Comment: Thank you! Works flawlessly. Throwing a curve ball…
`<div class="item">
 <div class="media">
<button class="zoomer">button</button>
</div>
</div>
`
What if the button is nested one layer deeper?

Comment: I think my edit beat your comment! Hahahaha!

Comment: You're way too quick!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) and access each element with e.target

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item > .zoomer')
.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', e => {
  
  e.target.classList.toggle('someClass')
}))
```

```css
.someClass{
  background:limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
<button class="zoomer">1</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
<button class="zoomer">2</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
<button class="zoomer">3</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
<button class="zoomer">4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since it's not toggling a class on the parent, you are just adding content to the button.

Comment: i edited the post to toggle a CSS class

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, are 7 `<button>`s that do various stuff -- details are commented in example.

```js
// Render 7 <menu>/<button> combos 
[...new Array(7)].forEach((item, index) => {
  document.querySelector('main').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
<menu class="item${index}">
  <button class="btn${index}">${index}</button>
</menu>`);
});
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.btn0*/

// Click <button> remove it's parent (which also removes the <button>)
document.querySelector('.btn0').onclick = function(e) {
  this.parentElement.remove();
}
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.btn1*/

// Click <button> -- <button> is removed but it's contents is left behind
document.querySelector('.btn1').onclick = unWrap;

function unWrap(e) {
  const clicked = e.target;
  const parent = clicked.parentElement;
  while (clicked.firstChild) {
    parent.insertBefore(clicked.firstChild, clicked);
  }
  clicked.remove();
}
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.btn4-6*/

// Collect all tags with a class that starts with "btn"
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='btn']");

// Adding .target class to the last 2 <button>s
btns.forEach((btn, idx) => {
  if (idx > 4) btn.classList.add('target')
});
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.btn2*/

// Target third <button> by index
/*
When <button> clicked, it's parent gets .hide class which is:
visibility:hidden which would normally hide the <button> as well, but
.btn2 has visibility explicitly set to visible
*/
btns[2].onclick = e => e.target.closest('menu').classList.toggle('hide');
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.btn3*/

/*
Everytime the <button> is clicked, a copy of itself is made and the
clones also have this ability as well
*/
btns[3].addEventListener('click', copySelf);

function copySelf(e) {
  let dupe = e.target.cloneNode(true);
  e.target.parentElement.append(dupe);
  dupe.onclick = copySelf;
}
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.btn4-6*/

/*
The click event is bound to the parent/ancestor tag <section>
Any click to any <button> will trigger the event handler. 
.btn4, .btn5, and .btn6 all react in a specific manner because
the event handler, delegateClick(e) is using flow control statements and 
specific criteria.
*/
document.querySelector('main').onclick = delegateClick;

let armed = false;

function delegateClick(e) {
  const clicked = e.target;
  if (clicked.matches('button') && !armed) {
    clicked.classList.add('armed');
    armed = true;
    return;
  }

  if (clicked.matches('.armed.target') && armed) {
    clicked.parentElement.style.cssText = `font-size: 5rem; margin: 0`
    clicked.replaceWith(``);
    return;
  }

  if (clicked.matches('.target') && armed) {
    clicked.classList.add('armed');
    return;
  }

  if (clicked.matches('.armed') && armed) {
    clicked.classList.remove('armed');
    armed = false;
  }
}
```

```css
menu {
  outline: dashed red 1px;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.btn2 {
  visibility: visible
}

.armed {
  animation: warning 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes warning {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.target.armed {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

button {
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```